# How do I prevent inertia when using mouseWheel in swiperJs?

Tags: swiper.js

I have the problem that the swiper continues to move after it has stopped swiping, is there any way I can completely remove this inertia?

When I swipe with the mouse pointer, the swiper moves one more space. Is there any way to make it stop immediately? Thank

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.